# Labels in viewcontroller are populated very slow

Tags: ios, json, swift3, uilabel, populate

I'm struggling with extreme slow population of the labels in my viewcontroller.

The script sends a userid to a php script. To script retrieves data related to the userid in an array and sends it back as a json response to my app. Then the labels in my viewcontroller are populated with the corresponding data from the json array (dictionary).

the print statements in the "do{}" are executed immediately in the console, but the population of the labels in the viewcontroller takes ages. Putting self.lblStreet.text = self.loadedStreet outside do{}, but still in the task, it gives the same slow result.

```
class CharDetailViewController: UIViewController {

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var lblUID: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblStreet: UILabel!

//URL to our web service
let URL_GET_DETAILS = "http://somesite.com/script.php"

var passedUID: String!
var loadedStreet: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: URL_GET_DETAILS)
    lblUID.text = passedUID

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let sendUID = lblUID.text
    let postParameters = "sendUID="+sendUID!;
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }

        do{
        let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        if let parseJSON = myJSON {
            var uid : String!
            uid = parseJSON["userid"] as! String?

            self.loadedStreet = parseJSON["street"] as! String!     
            self.lblStreet.text = parseJSON["street"] as! String!

            print(uid)
            print(self.loadedStreet)
         }     
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        }
    }     
    task.resume()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your UI on the main thread.  URLSession has you in a background thread. The appropriate code in Swift 3 is

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //your UI code
}
```

So your code should look more like this.

```
class CharDetailViewController: UIViewController {

 //Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var lblUID: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblStreet: UILabel!

//URL to our web service
let URL_GET_DETAILS = "http://somesite.com/script.php"

var passedUID: String!
var loadedStreet: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: URL_GET_DETAILS)
    lblUID.text = passedUID

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let sendUID = lblUID.text
    let postParameters = "sendUID="+sendUID!;
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest){
         data, response, error in

         if error != nil{
             print("error is \(error)")
             return;
         }

         do{
         let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

         if let parseJSON = myJSON {
             var uid : String!
             uid = parseJSON["userid"] as! String?

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              //your UI code
              self.loadedStreet = parseJSON["street"] as! String! 
              self.lblStreet.text = parseJSON["street"] as! String!
            }

           print(uid)
           print(self.loadedStreet)
        }     
    }catch {
     print(error)
    }
 }     
    task.resume()
 }

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit the UI anywhere other than the main thread. You can use this code to get the main thread in order to implement UI updates.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Update UI stuff here
});
```